# Editing Fields in Event Mode with FullCalendar + Javascript

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, fullcalendar

Good afternoon, I'm creating a simple calendar using the FullCalendar plugin, I'm almost done, but now I need to click on the desired event to show the information of the event and that there is an updated option in the image below you can see how are currently

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcJa2.png)

Now, continue with my codes up to this point, however, please note that I have already defined one updated button and the method that is used, but still  is not reaching at method. What I need is find out how to display the original data of the event and give the user a possibility to change and save this on database.

View:

```
<head>
<div class="row" >
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#new_event" class="btn btn-primary">Nova Tarefa</a>
    </div>
</div>


<script>



$(document).ready(function() {

  $.post('<?php echo base_url();?>calendar2/getEvents', 
  function(data){
  alert(data);

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      locale: 'pt-br',
      header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
      },
      defaultDate: new Date(),
      navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
      editable: true,
      eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
      editable: true,
      events: $.parseJSON(data),

      eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc){
        var id = event.id;
        var fi = event.start.format();
        var ff = event.end.format();

        $.post("<?php echo base_url();?>calendar2/updateEvents",
        {
          id:id,
          inicio:fi,
          fim:ff,
        },
        function(data){
          if(data == 1){
            alert('Evento atualizado');
          }else{
            alert('Evento Nao atualizado')
          }
        });    
      },

      eventResize: function(event, delta, revertFunc) {
        var id = event.id;
        var fi = event.start.format();
        var ff = event.end.format();

        $.post("<?php echo base_url();?>calendar2/updateEvents",
        {
          id:id,
          inicio:fi,
          fim:ff,
        },
        function(data){
          if(data == 1){
          //alert('Evento atualizado');
        }else{
         // alert('Evento não atualizado')
        }

        });  
      },

      // eventClick: function(event,jsEvent, view){
      //   $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents',event.id);
      //  }

      eventRender: function(event, element,data){
        var el = element.html();
        element.html("<div style='width:90%;float:left;'>" + el + "</div><div class='closeee' style='color:red; text-align:right;'>X</div>");

        element.find('.closeee').click(function(){
          if(!confirm("Excluir registro ??")){
            revertFunc();
          }else{
                var id = event.id
                $.post("<?php echo base_url();?>calendar2/deleteEvents",
                {
                  id:id,
                },
                function(data){
                  if(data == 1){
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('deleteEvents', event.id);
                  //alert('Tarefa Excluida');
                }else{
                 //alert('Tarefa não Excluida')
                }

                }); 
              }
          });
      },

      eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view){
        $('#mtitulo').html(event.title);
        $('#autor').html(event.autor);
        $('#inicioEdit').val(event.start);
        $('#importanciaEdit').val(event.impor);
        $('#descricaoEventoEdit').val(event.text);
        $('#modalEvento').modal();
      },

    });
  });
});

</script>

</head>


<body>

    <div id='calendar'></div>

</body>


<!-- Modal visualizar-->

<div class="modal fade" id="modalEvento" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mymodelLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header bg-red">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
      <h4 class="modal-title" id="mymodelLabel"> Editar Evento</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="nomeEvento">Nome Cliente</label> 
          <div class="form-control" id="mtitulo"></div>
        </div>  

        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label for="user">Responsavel</label> 
          <div class="form-control" id="autor"></div>
        </div>
      </div> 

      <div class="row"> 
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <div class="input-group date">
            <input type="text" class="form-control date" id="inicioEdit" />
            <div class="input-group-addon">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="importancia">Prioridade</label> 
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="importanciaEdit" />
        </div>
      </div>

       <div class="row"> 
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
          <label for="descricaoEvento">Descrição</label> 
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="descricaoEventoEdit" />
        </div> 
       </div>

    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="closeM" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
      <input href="http://localhost/sistema/calendar2/updateEvents2"  type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="btsalvar" value="Atualizar" />
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

Controler:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Calendar2 extends CI_controller{

    function __construct(){
        parent:: __construct();
        $this->load->model('calendar2Model', 'model', TRUE);
    } 

    public function index(){
        $this->template->set('title', 'Agenda');
        $this->template->load('layout', 'calendar_v.php');
        //$this->load->view('calendar_v.php');
    }

    public function getEvents(){
        $data = $this->model->get_events();
        echo json_encode($data);
    }

    public function updateEvents(){
        $param['id'] = $this->input->post('id');
        $param['inicio'] = $this->input->post('inicio');
        $param['fim'] = $this->input->post('fim');
        $r =  $this->model->updateEvents($param);
        echo json_encode($r);
    }

    public function updateEvents2(){
        die('');
    }

    public function deleteEvents(){
        $id = $this->input->post('id');
        $r = $this->model->deleteEvents($id);
        echo json_encode($r);
    }
```

Modal:

```
<?php

class calendar2Model extends CI_Model {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function get_events(){
        $this->db->select('idevento id, inicio start, fim end,descricaoEvento text, user autor,importancia impor ,cnome title');
        $this->db->from('eventos');
        $this->db->join('clientes','clientes.ccod = eventos.nomeEvento');
        return $this->db->get()->result();

    }   

    function inserir($data) {
        return $this->db->insert('eventos', $data);
    }

    function updateEvents($param) {
        $campos = array(
                'inicio' => $param['inicio'],
                'fim' => $param['fim']
            );

        $this->db->where('idevento', $param['id']);
        $this->db->update('eventos', $campos);

        if($this->db->affected_rows() == 1){
            return 1;
        } else{
            return 0;
            }       
        }

    function deleteEvents($id){
        $this->db->where('idevento', $id);
        $this->db->delete('eventos');
        if($this->db->affected_rows() == 1){
            return 1;
        } else{
            return 0;
            }       
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input href="http://localhost/sistema/calendar2/updateEvents2"  type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="btsalvar" value="Atualizar" />
```

'href' not an attributes for input tag
try to submitting the form to the server by giving it in action and method

```
<input type="submit" >
```